# It is necessary to translate the terms used in the questions to English?

Tags: discussion, support, localization

I wrote this question:

[O que é Neologismo e qual a diferença dele com Estrangeirismo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/100/o-que-%C3%A9-neologismo-e-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dela-com-estrangeirismo)

However, I was not sure whether to translate `neologismo` and `estrangeirismo` to English, when I wrote the phrase in English.

In this case is  it better to maintain or to translate these terms?

---

Eu formulei esta pergunta

[O que é Neologismo e qual a diferença dele com Estrangeirismo?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/100/o-que-%C3%A9-neologismo-e-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dela-com-estrangeirismo)

No entanto, eu fiquei em dúvida se traduzo as palavras `neologismo` e `estrangeirismo` para Inglês quando eu escrevi a frase em Inglês.

Neste tipo de caso qual é melhor manter o termo em Portugues ou traduzir para o inglês?

Comment: For the record, *neologismo* is clearly a *neologism* in English, but *estrangeirismo* is harder not because *foreignism* is not an English word — **it indeed is!** — but because it is rather uncommon (but very understandable, so I think everyone would know what you had meant if you used it). Normally one uses a familiar term like *loanword* for this, or sometimes *foreign term/phrase/expression*.

Answer (score 10):

As you are asking about these two words (*neologismo* and *estrangeirismo*) in portuguese, it should remain untraslated.

Also I think that in every sentence including a foreign word, that word should be in italics.

So the question in portuguese would be

> O que é Neologismo e qual a diferença dela com Estrangeirismo?

and in english it would be

> What is *Neologismo* and what is the difference with *Estrangeirismo*?